# RecordId in action

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, record

This component is an action that I launch through a button that exits on a component for the object obj__C , I want to retrieve in File__c , the id of obj__C , but with this code I don't know what does not work properly.

```
<template>
    
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Action__c" 
    onsuccess={handleSuccess} class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-8" >
        
   <div style="margin-left: 3% ;">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Fiche__c"  value={recordId} required disabled >
                </lightning-input-field>
            </div>
```

```
@api recordId;
@track  recordId; 
renderedCallback() {
    console.log('rendered------------');
    console.log(this.recordId + ' is provided');
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. As written, this post lacks enough detail to make it likely you will receive the help you want. Please **[edit]** it to be more specific about your desired behavior, what you see, and what you are actually *asking*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record):

```
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Fiche__c from '@salesforce/schema/Action__c.Fiche__c';
```

...

```
@api recordId;
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', { fields: [Fiche__c] })
handleRecordLoad({data, error}) {
  if(data) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need @track recordId.You can remove that line. @api recordId will get you recordId from record page button.

Try that and see if you are getting recordId in console.

Comment: , when I removed @track , I get in the console :  ` rendered----------- undefined is provided
   rendered------------
   a7W3L0000000NvyUAE is provided `

Comment: It seem like my renderedCallback is called two time , the first time the recordid is undefined and the second one is the correct id but I don't get it in html

Comment: Use connectedCallback instead

Comment: Is your field Fiche__c is self lookup. If not why you are passing value ={recordId} in it.

Comment: the field Fiche__c  is a Master-Detail with another object

Comment: Then don't pass this recordId as a value in it. Remove it

Comment: But how can I get the id of Fiche__c  , for being more clear , I have a component that return the information of an object (OBj1__C) and in this component I added an action that call me another object (OBj2__C) , that have a Master-Detail with (OBj1__C) , and what I need is to get the id of OBj1__C and put it in the value of the field in OBj2__C .

Comment: When you are using record edit form you don't need to pass value it will automatically fetch value from current record.

Comment: yes , but me I need to recuperate the value of the field that have a master detail with my record